# On onClick, click a DIV so it expands

Tags: onclick, submit

I want that if you click on text the search button appears, I try to do that by using this code:

```
<a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search" style="width:200%;" onClick="CLICK ON THE BUTTON DIV">Search with style</a>
                            <ul id="sb-search" class="sb-search" style="margin-right:30px;">
                            <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
                    <form>
                        <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Please enter search terms" type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
                        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="" id="search-submit">

                    </form>
                </div>
```

Does someone knows how to fix this? Maybe with jQuery? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using JQuery you can show the button on link click.

The HTML:

```
<a class="gn-icon gn-icon-search" id="search-text" style="width:200%;">Search with style</a>
<ul id="sb-search" class="sb-search" style="margin-right:30px;">
    <span class="sb-icon-search"></span>
    <form id="search-form">
        <input class="sb-search-input" placeholder="Please enter search terms" type="text" value="" name="search" id="search">
        <input class="sb-search-submit" type="submit" value="" id="search-submit">
    </form>
</ul>
```

The JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search-form').hide();
});

$('#search-text').click(function() {
    $('#search-form').show();
});
```